# Best practise for connecting physical site to aws region which is not local?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was hoping to get some help from you. At this point the information I'm looking for is probably quite high level. I have been searching for information, and for the most part have found what I'm looking for.

Essentially I'm looking to connect our UK based site to a AWS VPC. I have been looking at both Direct Connect and VPN options for this purpose. In the initial instance I would like to use a VPN to get things started. Naturally, I was going to have this VPC in a UK AWS region.

This would be straightforward enough, however due to a business demand, there is a requirement for us to offer an SFTP(or similar option) in the HK region quickly( before any need to have one in the UK), essentially escalating the move to using AWS. Ultimately, this new VPC in HK would eventually have a set of services shared to users in a remote site in HK. In the first instance only a SFTP is required however, which will mean I can make an externally facing service with credentials or tokens etc, forgoing the DC or VPN to the HK site for now.

My real question is: Would creating a VPN from UK site to AWS UK VPC, and then  VPN from UK VPC to HK VPC make sense? Or is it more sensible( aside from security concerns, which would be controlled) to connect a vpn directly from the UK site to the VPC in HK?

I really just need to move some data from our site about 3-4 times a day and make it available to an EC2 instance in the HK region?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Michael. This is very useful information. I appreciate you taking the time. Mister Smith: Thanks to you also for your reply. I had looked into the VPC options, and actually tried to set one up. It appears it isn't an option for HK region yet however. I found some articles online that added some weight to that opinion, so I gave up. Am I missing something and this functionality is available?. Apologies for the noobness :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to considered [inter-regional VPC Peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) between your HK&UK VPCs?

> A VPC peering connection is a networking connection between two VPCs that enables you to route traffic between them using private IPv4 addresses...
>
> AWS uses the existing infrastructure of a VPC to create a VPC peering
> connection; it is neither a gateway nor a VPN connection, and does not
> rely on a separate piece of physical hardware. There is no single
> point of failure for communication or a bandwidth bottleneck.
>
> A VPC peering connection helps you to facilitate the transfer of data.
> For example, if you have more than one AWS account, you can peer the
> VPCs across those accounts to create a file sharing network. You can
> also use a VPC peering connection to allow other VPCs to access
> resources you have in one of your VPCs.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this.  Yes, peering would be useful, but not for transit connectivity to a separate on-premise data center, as mentioned in the question.  Hong Kong is a high-cost region, with peering traffic outbound to London costing 250% more than peering traffic in the opposite direction, and Internet traffic 33% more.  Individual VPNs from the DC to each region would be advisable, as they would provide both resilience and cost-effectiveness.

Answer (score 0):

It would typically make more sense to provision the VPN directly from your site in the UK to the VPC in Hong Kong.  Later, create a second VPN from your site in UK to the VPC in UK.

You don't want all of your connectivity dependent on one VPN connection, when two would be more resilient to failure, of course, but there's a more significant issue, here.

AWS charges for what you use, and running traffic through a second VPC would incur unnecessary expense because you'd be using additional resources -- running the traffic through two VPCs, in this case, and using AWS's cross-region transport network.  It's an excellent network, but it isn't free.

There might be cases when, for performance reasons, you might do this deliberately, such as (for example) when your Internet connectivity to the remote region is suboptimal, but in that case you'd make a deliberate choice to use something with a higher cost in exchange for improved performance.

(I once had a customer in the UK accessing my services in the US heavily and they did not have good retry capabilities in case of errors.  I found that running their traffic through London and bringing it to the US using VPC peering was more reliable than their own trans-continental Internet connectivity, but this was a less costly arrangement than Hong Kong would be, for reasons explained below.)

Each AWS region potentially has different pricing for the same service, based on Amazon's operating costs in that geographic area.  Traffic into AWS is almost always free, but traffic out almost never is.

You don't want to pay AWS to transport data from Hong Kong to London and then pay again for egress to you on the VPN from London... but this point is not as obvious as it appears, since the cost of bandwidth varies by region.  In this specific case, Hong Kong is an expensive region.  Traffic out to the Internet is $0.12/GB and traffic out to AWS London using VPC peering is $0.09/GB.

Conversely, in AWS London, traffic out to the Internet is $0.09/GB and traffic out to AWS Hong Kong is $0.02/GB.

So your VPN traffic from the UK to AWS Hong Kong via AWS London would cost you $0.02 one way and $0.21 the other, while a VPN from the UK direct to AWS Hong Kong would cost $0.00 one way and $0.12 the other.

Additionally, [VPC peering does not directly support transit traffic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html) -- so you can't do what you appear to be proposing, using only a VPN connection and VPC peering.  You either need a [Transit Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/what-is-transit-gateway.html) or to roll your own solution using routers or proxies that run on EC2 hardware... or, simply create a VPN connection from your data center to each VPC.

Be sure to plan your IP addressing so that each VPC uses a range of private IP addresses that don't overlap with each other or any other (data center) network that you want to interconnect.